# Writing data from two related classes into a file

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble writing some data into a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Person{
public:
    Person();
    Person(string, string);
    string getFirst();
    string getLast();
private:
    string firstName, lastName;
};

class Employee{ 
public:
    Employee::Employee();
    Employee(string, string, float);
    Person getName();
    float getPay();
private:
    Person hiredHand;
    float salary;
};

Person::Person()
    :firstName(""), lastName("")
{
}

Person::Person(string first, string last)
    : firstName(first), lastName(last)
{
}

string Person::getFirst()
{
    return firstName;
}

string Person::getLast()
{
    return lastName;
}

Employee::Employee()
    : hiredHand("", ""), salary(0)
{
}

Employee::Employee(string first, string last, float sal)
    : hiredHand(first, last), salary(sal)
{
}

Person Employee::getName()
{
    return hiredHand;
}

float Employee::getPay()
{
    return salary;
}

int main()
{
    string first, last;
    float salary;

    cout << "Enter a first name, last name, and a salary." << endl;
    cin >> first >> last >> salary;
    Employee person1(first, last, salary);

    ofstream fileOut("Output.txt");
    if (!fileOut)
    {
        cerr << "Unable to open file for reading." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    Person guy1 = person1.getName();

    fileOut << guy1.getFirst << endl;
    fileOut << guy1.getLast << endl;
    fileOut << fixed << setprecision(2) << "$" << person1.getPay() << endl;
    fileOut.close();
}
```

I'm not sure how i can pull out the data in the Person class from the Employee Class.
My objective is to be able to print out the first name, last name, and salary all on separate lines in a file. So far only salary works..

#### Update:

I've added some getters to the class Person but it's giving me an error when i try to print it.

```
Error1: error C3867: 'Person::getFirst': function call missing argument list; use '&Person::getFirst' to create a pointer to member 
Error2: error C3867: 'Person::getLast': function call missing argument list; use '&Person::getLast' to create a pointer to member
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code i was looking for :)

```
fileOut << person1.getName().getFirst() << endl;
fileOut << person1.getName().getLast() << endl;
fileOut << fixed << setprecision(2) << "$" << person1.getPay() << endl;
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: I'm glad you solved it! If you believe it's the right answer then you can mark it as the accepted answer. Also welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are referring to?

```
string Person::getFirstName()
{
  return firstName;
}
```

and then:

```
string Employee::getFirstName()
{
    return hiredHand.getFirstName();
}
```

Alternatively you can try this solution instead (if we stick to your example):

```
fileOut << guy1.getFirst() << endl;
fileOut << guy1.getLast() << endl;
```

Comment: sure just noticed;then he could just add some getter

Comment: I've added some getters to retrieve the data from class Person but it's giving me an error:   error C3867: 'Person::getFirst': function call missing argument list; use '&Person::getFirst' to create a pointer to member

Comment: @JustinY.: Then you should have posted that

Comment: @Giorgi: He did, as a comment, which is the correct place for a problem with a specific answer.

Comment: @JustinY.: You need to use `fileOut << person1.getName().getFirstName()`.  Not sure if you wrote `Person::getFirst()` or `person1.getName().getFirst`, but those are wrong.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Maybe he should also have shown code that is what I meant - hardly I can deduce issue now directly from error

Comment: @MooingDuck: I'm sorry! Bit new to this site but you've solved my problem with that last bit of code! thank you so much!

Comment: @Giorgi: you should probably make the code in your answer refer to itself, rather than mixing your suggestions with his (different) implementations.  What you have now is kind of confusing.

Comment: @MooingDuck:Is it still confusing?

Comment: @Giorgi: Eh.  Close enough for a +1.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting your errors because you were suppose to call the function with the `()` parentheses at the end of the function name. So it would be like Giorgi's answer. It would make more sense for your `getName()` function to return the first name and last name as string instead of returning as a `Person` (for that you should of renamed the function to `getPerson`). If you want the `getName` function to return the name then you will need to change the return type to string then change the function definition to something like this:

```
string Employee::getName()
{
    return hiredHand.getFirst() + " " + hiredHand.getLast();
}
```

For further reference, it makes even more sense to have the `Employee` class derive from `Person` since an employee IS a person, well I hope he/she is...:P